# Hot to increase height of contentSize for wkWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

Hot to increase height of contentSize for wkWebView?

Tried this but doesn't work:

```
[[self.webView scrollView]setContentSize:CGSizeMake([[[self webView]scrollView] contentSize].width, [[[self webView]scrollView] contentSize].height+300)];
```

Technically it increased but practically still can't scroll more.

Comment: Just a suggestion to make the code a little clearer and more modern:  `CGSize currentSize = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize;` then `CGSize tallerSize = (CGSize) { currentSize.width, currentSize.height + 100 };` then `self.webView.scrollView.contentSize = taller;`

Answer (score 0):

It works when you try to increase content size after webView finish load try this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [[self.webView scrollView]setContentSize:CGSizeMake([[[self webView]scrollView] contentSize].width, [[[self webView]scrollView] contentSize].height+100)];
}
```

Comment: unfortunately It doesn't work. I've put the code in "didFinishNavigation" method with 3 seconds delay :(
P.S. It's wkWebView not a UIWebView my mistake.